# LwjglCanvas with JFrame resizing

Tags: java, swing, opengl, libgdx, jframe

I have a desktop LibGDX project and my main (*DesktopLauncher*) class extends JFrame (it will be undecorated and non-resizable). I render the LibGDX OpenGL canvas in LwjglCanvas which is added to the container as a component. Now here is the weird problem: Sometimes I can see 3-4-5px border around the canvas that enables some suspicious resizing.

[image: Not cool resizing]

Here is my class:

```
    public DesktopLauncher() {

    this.setUndecorated(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setTitle("Evil Engine (v. Lambda)");

    Container container = this.getContentPane();
    this.canvas = new LwjglCanvas(new Main(DesktopLauncher.inst));

    // this.canvas.getCanvas().setLocation(200, -200);

    // height of the task bar
    int taskBarSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(this.getGraphicsConfiguration()).bottom;
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

    this.canvas.getCanvas().setSize(screenSize.width, screenSize.height - taskBarSize);

    container.add(this.canvas.getCanvas(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

    this.pack();

    this.setVisible(true);
}
```

The problem can be seen when setUndecorated is true. I tried to move the canvas (*the setLocation() line*) and I saw that there is a border around it:
[image: Border around canvas]

And as a undecorated window:
[image: Border around canvas-undecorated]

I have tried many things but nothing worked:

- I changed the layout type
- I created a new JPanel, added the canvas into it and set as setContentPane()
- tried setPreferedSize, setMaximumSize, setMinimumSize
- searched for ...setBorder() or ..setResizable() methods with no success

How I can get rid of this awful border around the canvas?

Comment: remove the jframe extension and just put this on your code before launch System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.opengl.Window.undecorated", "true");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your DesktopLauncher should be like this:

```
public class DesktopLauncher {
    public static void main (String[] arg) {
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        config.height =1024;
        config.width= 768;
        config.resizable = false;
        config.title= "My App Title";
        System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.opengl.Window.undecorated", "true"); 
        new LwjglApplication(new Game(), config);
    }
}
```

so now you have a bordeless, unresizeable game window.

For your case, if you still want to use it with swing, just to this instead:

```
public DesktopLauncher() {

    this.setUndecorated(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setTitle("Evil Engine (v. Lambda)");

    Container container = this.getContentPane();
    LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
    config.resizable = false;
    System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.opengl.Window.undecorated", "true"); 
    this.canvas = new LwjglCanvas(new Main(DesktopLauncher.inst),config);

    // this.canvas.getCanvas().setLocation(200, -200);

    // height of the task bar
    int taskBarSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(this.getGraphicsConfiguration()).bottom;
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

    this.canvas.getCanvas().setSize(screenSize.width, screenSize.height - taskBarSize);

    container.add(this.canvas.getCanvas(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

    this.pack();

    this.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Cool, but it won't do the job - that will disable Java Swing, and I need it (I need to use some of the swing functionalities)....

Comment: it still applies to your case, just create the config and set it on this.canvas = new LwjglCanvas(new Main(DesktopLauncher.inst),config); and before set System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.opengl.Window.undecorated", "true");  it should work like a charm.